# 400 error in stripe cli when listening to webhooks in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

Hey everybody I get this 400 error below  when I listen to stripewebhooks.

Stripe cli command => `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks`

After successful payment =>

```
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> charge.succeeded [evt_3OihNVAHrCXdaN2D1FwDqPAg]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_3OihNVAHrCXdaN2D1FwDqPAg]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> customer.subscription.created [evt_1OihNXAHrCXdaN2DEwvHAQ9w]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1OihNXAHrCXdaN2DEwvHAQ9w]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> customer.subscription.updated [evt_1OihNXAHrCXdaN2DUpdKFe5Y]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1OihNXAHrCXdaN2DUpdKFe5Y]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3OihNVAHrCXdaN2D19uFzM2H]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_3OihNVAHrCXdaN2D19uFzM2H]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> payment_intent.created [evt_3OihNVAHrCXdaN2D1klShlPc]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_3OihNVAHrCXdaN2D1klShlPc]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> invoice.created [evt_1OihNXAHrCXdaN2DXgLhnMb2]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1OihNXAHrCXdaN2DXgLhnMb2]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> invoice.finalized [evt_1OihNYAHrCXdaN2DID3UutqE]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1OihNYAHrCXdaN2DID3UutqE]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> invoice.updated [evt_1OihNYAHrCXdaN2DM0TgxtvW]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1OihNYAHrCXdaN2DM0TgxtvW]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> invoice.paid [evt_1OihNYAHrCXdaN2D8kt2YgNg]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1OihNYAHrCXdaN2D8kt2YgNg]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 --> invoice.payment_succeeded [evt_1OihNYAHrCXdaN2Dbdeq4Bn9]
2024-02-11 19:03:48 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1OihNYAHrCXdaN2Dbdeq4Bn9]
2024-02-11 19:03:50 --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1OihNZAHrCXdaN2DLafn3NZO]
2024-02-11 19:03:50 <-- [400] POST http://localhost:3000/stripe/webhooks [evt_1OihNZAHrCXdaN2DLafn3NZO]
```

index.js in the backend =>

```
// Create app and the clients
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// making sure requests from the client side work
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  credentials: true,
}));

// middleware to read body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: "application/json"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Create stripe
const stripe = Stripe("stripe api key");

// Stripe webhook
const webhookSecret = "webhook secret key";

// Create stripe customer for prepayment
app.post("/user/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, name, data: reqData } = req.body;
  
  const userData = reqData;
  console.log("user before try:", userData);

  // Store user's stripe customer id
  try {
    if (await email && await name) {
      const customer = await createStripeCustomer({ email, name });
      console.log("stripe cstomer was created:", customer);

      // Check if userData is defined
      if (userData) {
        const userId = userData;
        console.log("user after try:", userId);
    
        // inserting stripe customer id into supabase accounts table
        const { error: insertError } = await supabase 
          .from('accounts')
          .update({ stripeid: customer.id })
          .eq("id", userId)
    
        if (insertError) {
          console.log("Error inserting stripe id into accounts", insertError);
        } else {
          console.log("stripeID was inserted into user account:", name, customer.id);
        }

      } else {
        console.log("Userdata was not defined", userData);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("email and name not present stripe customer was not created.", email, name);
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error creating stripe customer", error);
    console.log("email and name failed:", email, name );
  }
  // Send response to the client
  res.status(200).send("request successful");
});

// Create stripe customer
async function createStripeCustomer({ name, email }) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-async-promise-executor
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const Customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        name: name,
        email: email,
      });

      resolve(Customer);
      console.log("Stripe customer was created", Customer);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const { customerId, priceId } = req.body;
  console.log("recived customer and priceId, creating session", customerId, priceId);

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      customer: customerId,
      payment_method_types: [
        "card",
      ],
      line_items: [
        {
          price: priceId,
          quantity: 1,
        }
      ],
      mode: "subscription",
      success_url: 'https://localhost:5173/payment/success', // TODO: replace with real url
      cancel_url: 'https://localhost:5173/pricing', // TODO: replace with real url
    })
    res.json({ id: session.id })
});

// Stripe webhooks!
app.post('/stripe/webhooks', (req, res) => {
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, sig, webhookSecret);
  }
  catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded': {
      const email = event['data']['object']['receipt_email'] // contains the email that will recive the recipt for the payment (users email usually)
      console.log(`PaymentIntent was successful for ${email}!`)

      console.log("updating user plan now!")
      break;
    }
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      return res.status(400).end();
  }

  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.json({received: true});
})
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Also if it's important, for some reason I got error 404 before, but now I get 400 instead! Any help would be much
appreciated
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added any logging to your Express application to catch the exception that is returning the `400` error? I suspect that the `constructEvent` is throwing an error on your `/stripe/webhooks` endpoint. The likelihood is that you're not passing it the raw request body, which it expects, and instead JSON because of your middleware.

I recommend adapting your code to following the examplefrom the Node.js SDK [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/express/main.ts#L34), which uses `express.raw()` [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.raw).

Comment: Yep that was the error, I was not passing the request body raw. Thank you for your help!